# In Node/raw ES6, how could I emit an event from a parent class and trigger an event in the child class from their respective constructors?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, event-handling

I'm currently working on exercism.io's "JS track - react project" (no not that react). The exercise is to make classes that react to one another's actions. I wasn't sure if inheritance was the best bet, but I feel like it's as close as I'm going to get. (P.S. This is my first post here, I tried quite a few places before deciding to ask my first question here. ('P.P.S.') => 'Howdy' :)

```
`class InputCell extends EventEmitter {
  constructor(value) {
    super(value);
    this.value = value;
  }

  setValue(value) {
    this.value = value;

    // I'm assuming this emitter doesn't leave the scope of the object it creates?
    this.emit('cellChange');
  }
}

class ComputeCell extends InputCell {
  constructor(cells, compute) {
    super(cells, compute);
    this.value = compute(cells);

    // super wasn't my first choice, but 'this' didn't work either
    super.on('cellChange', () => compute(cells));
  }
}`
```

Edit- My apologies, here is the failing test I run.

```
`  test('compute cells update value when inputs are changed', () => {
    const inputCell = new InputCell(1);

    const computeCell = new ComputeCell(
      [inputCell], inputs => inputs[0].value + 1
    );

    inputCell.setValue(3);

    expect(computeCell.value).toEqual(4);
  });
```

`

Comment: "*super wasn't my first choice, but 'this' didn't work either*" - **what** does not work? How are you creating an instance, what methods do you call, and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: No, inheritance seems to be the wrong choice if you want to listen to events of *another* object. The event emitter is fine there. It sounds like your `ComputeCell` takes an array of `InputCells` as its argument, right?

Comment: On the other hand, inheritance could be a solution, and you'd just overwrite the `setValue` method. You would not use events then, however.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have mentioned the test script for this. All it does though is instantiate each object, calls the instantiated "inputCell.setValue" and then asserts the value of the instantiated computeCell to see if it updated when inputCell's setValue() is called.

Comment: Yes, as expected in my second comment. No, `ComputeCell` should *not* inherit from `InputCell`, it should make use of the `InputCell` instance that it receives in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

@TJ Allen: I'm stuck on the same exercise, but I found the solutions page: https://exercism.io/tracks/javascript/exercises/react/solutions

it took some looking but I found this explanation to be simple enough for my understanding (specifically for the test case you posted):

```
export class InputCell {
  constructor(value) { // test 1: accepts input
    this.value = value;
  }

  setValue(value) {
    this.value = value; // test 2: allows input  value to be set
  }
}

export class ComputeCell {
  constructor(inputCells, func) { // test 3: allows setting compute cells
    this.inputs = inputCells;
    this.func = func;
  }

  get value() {
    return this.func(this.inputs); // test 5: compute cells update value when inputs are changed
  }
}
```

For other exercism.io users, note that I've left-out a comment for **test 4:** *compute cell takes inputs in correct order* as it was less relevant to the question asked here.

Edit: Personally, I think the *wording* of that specific test 5 case is vague and confusing.

> "compute cells update value when inputs are changed"

Which inputs and where? It sounds like its asking you to some kind of event listener so that the values inside `InputCell` automatically trigger the values inside `ComputeCell` to change -- bc I thought the same.

But looking at the test, I think what they're actually asking for is: if you initialize a new instance of `InputCell` with a number and *pass* that instance as an argument to create a new instance of `ComputeCell` then your new `ComputeCell` instance will have updated its `value`(through the getter) based on the `value` of the `InputCell` instance you passed to it. It might have been clearer if the test message logged something this:

> "compute cells return different value when called with new inputs"

still probably not as clear as I'd like, but less misleading imo.